# change document root

Tags: php, html, apache

I have apache2 and need to change the document root folder from:

```
   /var/www/
```

to

```
  /var/www/SV/
```

Now, I have checked the httpd.conf file, but it is empty, so I read someplace that all info is nowdays placed into apache.conf.

However, I cant find any "DocumentRoot" line in that file. Should I add that line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, fixed it.

Located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default